# Copy file from server and paste it into a table in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to read a file located at

`/home/user/public/html/conf.php`

i have privileges to read it since im connecting with Postgres user

i use this query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cmd_exec;
CREATE TABLE cmd_exec(cmd_output text);
COPY cmd_exec FROM PROGRAM $$cd /home/user/public_html/includes/;cat conf.php$$;
SELECT * FROM cmd_exec;
```

i face this error:

> Warning: pg_query (): Query failed: ERROR: extra data after last
> expected column CONTEXT: COPY cmd_exec, line 3: "switch ($ _SESSION
> ['LANG_ID']) {" in /home/user/..

i tried this query as a solution :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cmd_exec;
CREATE TABLE cmd_exec(t TEXT);
COPY cmd_exec FROM $$/home/user/public_html/includes/conf.php$$;
SELECT * FROM cmd_exec limit 1 offset 0;
```

still the same error, i expect reading the whole file .

EDIT:
the conf.php file containing php codes for db connections but i dont have the real src code of it .

Comment: The error message has a different opinion about what is in the file, a switch statement. Are you sure your example is drawing from the correct place?

Comment: @jjanes what do you mean?

Comment: I mean `line 3: "switch ($ _SESSION ['LANG_ID']) {"` definitely does not resemble the third line you show, `$db_n = "db_name";`.  PostgreSQL doesn't fabricate its error messages out of thin air; where does that switch statement it quotes come from?

Comment: @jjanes , it seems you are right, but how can i read the full script ?

Comment: @jjanes i edited the question,

Comment: any help ? i tried a lot